# Runnable jar file does not find resources

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have created a jar file that runs the login screen. When I enter the user's credentials, it uses an XML file to validate the credentials. My jar file does not seem to find this XML file. Here is my file directory:
 [image]

My jar file is created like this:
[image]

The users.xml file is loaded like this

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/users.xml");
String path = url.getPath();
String loginQuery = "for $x in doc('"+ path +"')//User where ($x/Username='" + username +"') "
 + " and ($x/Password='" + password + "') return data($x/Name)";
```

My project works fine on eclipse when I run it. I have no idea why my jar doesn't work

Comment: Have you checked your generated jar for the `users.xml` file? It needs to appear directly in the root folder of your jar.

Comment: @mabi yes it is in the root of my jar file

Comment: And the error is that you get `url == null`? Only thing I can think of is trying a different class loader, ie using `getSystemResource()`.

Comment: @mabi yes it was returning a nullpointer exception. I tried getSystemResource() as well it can't locate the file

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a problem with your packaging. I just compiled a test program, showing stuff works as expected:

```
mabi@terra ~ $ cat /tmp/test/Test.java
import java.net.URL;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test instance = new Test();
        URL absDynRes = instance.getClass().getResource("/users.xml");
        if (absDynRes == null) {
            System.out.println("Absolute dynamic URL is null");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Got: " + absDynRes);
        }
    }
}
```

Compile and run:

```
mabi@terra ~ $ cd /tmp/test/ && javac Test.java 
mabi@terra /tmp/test $ jar cfe test.jar Test -C /tmp/test Test.class users.xml
mabi@terra /tmp/test $ java -jar test.jar
Got: jar:file:/tmp/test/test.jar!/users.xml
```

Either you don't have the file in your jar or the class returned by `getClass()` resides in a different jar then the one containing `users.xml`.